# MYSQL, display non for non associate value

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

please help me with this
I have two tables, 
the first one is province with `province_id(primary key), province_name`, propose that `province_id` could be null

the second is staff with `staff_id(primary key), staff_name, province_id`

the question is display `staff_id, staff_name, province_name`, and any staff who does not belong to any province, display "none", **use only one query**

I did this

```
SELECT staff_id, staff_name, province.province_name
FROM staff
INNER JOIN province
ON staff.province_id = province.province_id;
```

Please help me to insert none value for those staff who not belong to any province.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for `staff` members who don't belong to any `province`, you should use an **`outer`** join, not an `inner` one.
From there, simply apply `ifnull` to the result:

```
SELECT          staff_id, staff_name, IFNULL(province.province_name, 'none')
FROM            staff
LEFT OUTER JOIN province
ON              staff.province_id = province.province_id;
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I really appreciate it, you save me :), cheers

Comment: @KucKu you're welcome. You can accept the answer in order to mark that it solves the issue in case someone else with a similar problem comes over this page.